# How do i download a whole project from perforce onto a device?

Tags: perforce, unreal-engine4

So, to give some context. Recently i had to delete the whole project from my personal computer for some reasons. Now i want to download the whole project back onto my PC but don't know how. I assume that the clone button would do that (since that's what it does on Git) but seems to not be the case. I then tried to force update all the files thinking it would download the missing ones. It kinda works, i think but it takes awfully long. It took around 16 hours to update a folder that was about 20GB in size.

The project in question is a UE4 project, in case that's important

Now the question. How can i, most easily, download the whole project from perforce onto my PC? Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In the future, you can simplify this by using Perforce's "remove from workspace" or `p4 sync #none` command to delete the project from your PC.  If you use Perforce's commands to clean up the workspace, it will:

1. not delete anything that isn't backed up to Perforce (i.e. files you didn't add to Perforce will be safe)
2. keep track of what you deleted (so the next time you do a normal "sync" it will just put it all back, without the force flag)

In the situation you found yourself in, an option apart from "force download" is the `p4 clean` command, which will reset your workspace's state to whatever you last synced to.  Note that this will *not* necessarily preserve any local changes, but if you delete the entire workspace root this isn't a concern.

The time it takes to re-sync a folder is largely a function of your network speed to the Perforce server, but in some cases can be improved by parallelization (I believe P4V will do this automatically, and it's easy to enable via the command line, but if you're syncing via the UE4 plugin this may not be the case).  https://community.perforce.com/s/article/9064